# open file in constructor c++

Tags: c++, file-handling

I am trying to open a file in constructor and writing into that file from other function, but file is not created.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstring>

#define BAD_FILE_NAME_PATTERN "MYFILE_"
#define BAD_FILE_PATH "$HOME/"


class A
{
        private:
        std::ofstream m_badReprtLogFilePtr;
        char *m_badReprtLogFilePtrName;

        public:
        void rechargeEventBadFileHandler();
        void writeToFile();
        A();
};

A::A()
{
        time_t     now = time(0);
        struct tm  tstruct;
        char dateTime[80];
        tstruct = *localtime(&now);
        strftime(dateTime, sizeof(dateTime), "%F_%H%M%S", &tstruct);
        m_badReprtLogFilePtrName = new char[strlen(BAD_FILE_NAME_PATTERN) + sizeof(dateTime)];
        strcpy(m_badReprtLogFilePtrName,BAD_FILE_PATH);
        strcat(m_badReprtLogFilePtrName,BAD_FILE_NAME_PATTERN);
        strncat(m_badReprtLogFilePtrName,dateTime,sizeof(dateTime));
        strcat(m_badReprtLogFilePtrName,".bad");
        std::cout<< "Bad File Name " << m_badReprtLogFilePtrName << std::endl;
        m_badReprtLogFilePtr.open(m_badReprtLogFilePtrName, std::ios::out | std::ios::app);
        if(!m_badReprtLogFilePtr.is_open())
        {
           std::cout<<"Error opening Bad file"<<std::endl;
        }
}

void A::writeToFile()
{
        m_badReprtLogFilePtr << "Writting to BAD FILE"<<std::endl;
}

/*
A::~A()
{
        m_badReprtLogFilePtr.close();
}
*/

int main()
{
        A obj;
        obj.writeToFile();
        return 0;
}
```

I got the problem, problem is with path, but how to fix this

Comment: There's more C in there, than C++!!

Comment: do me a favor, run the program once and then modify the program and add the following flag while opening the file. std::ios::noreplace. does the file open the second time you run the program ?

Comment: Environment variables like `$HOME` are not part of the file system. Unless you have a directory literally called "$HOME", you need to expand it yourself (see e.g. `getenv`).

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/06cc26d6e68e0eee my guess: you forgot to create the directory.

Comment: Offtopic: You can shorten this strcpy / strcat part to something like:
`snprintf(m_badReprtLogFilePtrName, ..., "%s%s%s.bad", BAD_FILE_PATH, BAD_FILE_NAME_PATTERN, dateTime)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with:

```
#define BAD_FILE_PATH "$HOME/"
```

You can use `getenv("HOME")` on Unix or concatenate the results of `getenv("HOMEDRIVE")` and `getenv("HOMEPATH")` on Windows.

**e.g. On Unix**

```
strcpy(m_badReprtLogFilePtrName,getenv("HOME"));
strcat(m_badReprtLogFilePtrName,"/");
```

Comment: Thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 1):

Things to fix:

- the size of the `m_badReprtLogFilePtrName` array is wrong. There is space for just the name and the date (not for the path, the extension and the null terminating character).
- `strncat(m_badReprtLogFilePtrName,dateTime,sizeof(dateTime));`.

  The size argument of `strncat` is the amount of space left after the end of the string that's already in the target. **You're using the source size**.
- there's a memory leak (the destructor should delete `m_badReprtLogFilePtrName`).
- you should expand the `$HOME` path (`std::getenv`). For `getenv` to work `BAD_FILE_PATH` should be defined as:

  ```
  #define BAD_FILE_PATH "HOME"
  ```

  (take a look at [getenv on cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/getenv)).
- you should use `std::string`

So something like:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#define BAD_FILE_NAME_PATTERN "MYFILE_"
#define BAD_FILE_PATH "HOME"

class A
{
public:
  A();

  // ...

private:
  std::ofstream m_badReprtLogFilePtr;
  std::string m_badReprtLogFilePtrName;
};

A::A()
{
  time_t now = time(0);

  struct tm tstruct;
  char dateTime[80];
  tstruct = *localtime(&now);

  strftime(dateTime, sizeof(dateTime), "%F_%H%M%S", &tstruct);

  char *path = std::getenv(BAD_FILE_PATH);
  if (path)
    m_badReprtLogFilePtrName = std::string(path) + "/";

  m_badReprtLogFilePtrName += BAD_FILE_NAME_PATTERN;
  m_badReprtLogFilePtrName += dateTime;
  m_badReprtLogFilePtrName += ".bad";

  std::cout << "Bad File Name " << m_badReprtLogFilePtrName << "\n";

  m_badReprtLogFilePtr.open(m_badReprtLogFilePtrName.c_str(),
                            std::ios::out | std::ios::app);

  if (!m_badReprtLogFilePtr.is_open())
    std::cout << "Error opening Bad file\n";
}
```

probably works (of course there are many other things to be improved).

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things wrong.

A C or C++ program (most of your code is using C techniques, even if you are building it with a C++ compiler) does not interpret the meaning of `$HOME`.  That is up to the shell (under unix) and needs to be expanded in other ways (e.g. using `getenv()`).

The number of characters allocated to  `m_badReprtLogFilePtrName` is equal to `strlen(BAD_FILE_NAME_PATTERN) + sizeof(dateTime)`.   The `strcpy()`, `strcat()`, and `strncat()` calls potentially write `strlen(BAD_FILE_PATH) + strlen(BAD_FILE_NAME_PATTERN) + min(strlen(dateTime), sizeof dateTime) + strlen(".bad") + 1` characters to that buffer.   Odds are, the number of characters being written exceeds the allocated length, so the result is undefined behaviour.

Instead of manually allocating arrays of character with operator `new`, try using the standard `std::string` class to manage strings.    Then the string will be cleaned up nicely when the object is destroyed, rather than leaked as it currently is.

Oh:  "writing" is spelt with one 't'.